# CSS3 Pseudo :after horizontal scroll even overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I am developing a responsible page using bootstrap, For a `<div>` content i am using `:before` and `:after` pseudo for the screen size. Below is the code, its working fine. But the horizontal scroll is appearing, even the overflow is hidden. Please help to remove the horizontal scroll.

**CSS**

```
.text_box{
 background:#ff0000;
 width:1000px;
 height:200px;
 margin: 0 0 19px;
 padding: 20px 0 25px;
 position: relative;
 color:#ffffff;
 }

.text_box:before{
background:#ff0000;
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-99%;
z-index:-1;
content:'';
}

.text_box:after {   
background: #ff0000;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
right: -99%;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="text_box">
Hello World !!!    
</div>
```

Comment: I would be better if you mention, what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 100% width from :after and :next class. Update your CSS like below.

```
.text_box:before{
background:#ff0000;
display:block;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-99%;
z-index:-1;
content:'';
}

.text_box:after {   
background: #ff0000;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
right: -99%;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `left: -99%` and `right: -99%` can also help you.

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sthKz)